# A JOIN B vs B JOIN A

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

when dealing with large datasets where Table A has considerably very less no of rows when compared to B. Is there any difference between joining Table **A** with **B** and **B** with **A** in the query below

SELECT A.col_PK , B.col_PK FROM **A** INNER JOIN **B** ON A.col_PK = A.col_PK WHERE A.col_2 = "0001";

Comment: It depends of the kind of join (LEFT, INNER,etc)

Comment: If you do select *, the columns show up in different order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

For an `INNER JOIN`, there is no difference in functionality (order does make a difference for outer joins).  For performance, the optimizer generally chooses the best ordering.

Under some circumstances, when your query has long sequences of joins, the optimizer may not be able to consider all options.  In those cases, the ordering *could* make a difference to the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Result matters on which type on `JOIN` you use.
Refer
[TYPES OF JOINS AND THEIR WORKING](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/712941/Types-of-Join-in-SQL-Server)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of JOIN (LEFT OR RIGHT) you use. It doesn't make any difference with equijoin.