# Difference between A JOIN B vs B JOIN A

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I am re-asking this question because I believe it has been incorrectly closed without a satisfatory answer:
Original Question:
   When dealing with large datasets where Table A has considerably less number of rows when compared to B, is there any difference between joining Table A with B and B with A?
[A JOIN B vs B JOIN A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365875/a-join-b-vs-b-join-a)

Comment: It was most likely closed as to broad because there are too many things that would affect the performance of such a query than what is stated in your question. IOW, it just isn't that simple.

Answer (score 1):

hence join will fetch matching records from both tables so logically there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There can be a huge difference.
    When doing a regular JOIN, MySQL will try to automatically detect the order in which to join the 2 tables. But, sometimes, the way that it decides to go is not the best. This is specially true if the large table has an Index and the small table does not (or is a tempTable). MySQL tends to favor using indexes over using un-indexed tables as its primary table.
    Recently I had a query taking several seconds. It was a case of A JOIN B where A was BIG and indexed and B was small.
    When I updated to A RIGHT JOIN B the performance improved to a fraction of a second.

Comment: Your question was about `JOIN`.  This answer fails to say that the query is performed differently because of the _specified order of the tables_, rather that the indexes and/or `RIGHT` matters.  That is a different issue.

Comment: And, yes, the Optimizer has some guidelines based on indexes, etc, but they do _not_ include `A JOIN B` vs `B JOIN A`.